# Python Flask - Uploading file to Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, flask

I'm pretty new to Pandas and Flask, trying to leverage it to output a summarised version of a CSV containing survey feedback that I can email to users periodically.

As a standalone function, it works so long as I give it an input file that's specified (e.g. 'users/sample.csv') and outfile but when running as part of an application and using an uploaded html file, it fails with 
**TypeError: csuppfb() takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)**

Essentially I want to pass the uploaded file to the function, and have Pandas do its thing but it doesn't get that far. Below is the code:

```
import re,os
import beatbox
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from weasyprint import HTML
from os.path import isfile,join
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for,render_template,json as fjson,send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from mapping import Autotagging,Manualtagging
from defs import *

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'
PIVOT_FOLDER = './pivot'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['csv'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['PIVOT_FOLDER']= PIVOT_FOLDER

@app.route('/feedback',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedback():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = randomword(6)+'_'+secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['PIVOT_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('csuppfb',df=filename))

    return render_template('mappingtest.html')

@app.route('/csuppfb', methods=['POST','GET'])
def csuppfb(df,infile, index_list=["Case Owner","Case Number","Support Survey - Service rating"], value_list = ["Age (Hours)"]):
    """
    Creating a pivot table from the raw dataframe and returning it as a dataframe
    """
    table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=index_list, values = value_list, 
                    aggfunc=[np.sum,np.mean], fill_value=0)
    return table

def get_summary_stats(df, product):
    """
    Get a stats summary 
    """
    results.append(df[df["Support Survey - Service rating"]==product]["Closed"].mean())
    results.append(df[df["Support Survey - Service rating"]==product]["Age (Hours)"].mean())
    return results

def dataform(df):
    """
    Take the dataframe and output it in html to output a pdf report or display on a web page
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    csuppreport = pivot_table(df,filename)
    agent_df = []
    for agent in csuppreport.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
        agent_df.append([agent, csuppreport.xs(agent, level=0).to_html()])
    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
    template = env.get_template("csupp.html")


template_vars={"title": "CSUPP FB REPORT", 
            "Excellent": get_summary_stats(df,"Excellent"),
            "Good": get_summary_stats(df,"Good"),
            "csupp_pivot_table": csuppreport.to_html(),
            "agent_detail": agent_df}

html_out = template.render(template_vars)
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf(args.outfile.name,stylesheets=["style.css"])
return render_template('csupp.html')
```

What's the best way to have the file I've uploaded be used as the dataframe argument in 
def csuppfb(df,infile...
?

Any advice would be very much appreciated. I've a feeling it's something glaringly obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the args object from request which contains all the url params
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object

See this basic example:

```
@app.route('/csuppfb', methods=['POST','GET'])
    def csuppfb():
        if request.args['df'] :
            df = request.args['df']
            #Do your panda stuff here. Instead of returning the filename :D
            return str(df)
        else :
            return 'nofile'
```